# Yii2 controller/action in windows scheduler

Tags: yii2, windows-task-scheduler

I have found a few questions and answers for this, but I can't make it work. I have a controller (extending `controller`), and an action. When I try this in PowerShell (as admin):

```
C:\wamp64\www\project\yii controller/action
```

a black **cmd** window is appearing for a moment but certainly doesn't do what it supposed to do, otherwise I could see the results what I'm waiting for. How can I check what is going on in this **cmd** window? Maybe there is an error message that could help me to find out what is wrong. I have tried `-noexit` but it's still disappearing. 
If I run the controller/action in a browser, it is working.
Once it is working I guess I can add it to windows scheduler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out:

first, the controller has to be in `project\commands`. You are in your project folder in `CMD` and run the following command:

```
yii controller/action
```

and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Try executing as
C:\wamp64\www\project\yii.bat controller/action